# How to zoom image to fullscreen mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, zooming

I have paging `UIScrollView` with images. I want to implement animated zooming of image to fullscreen on some gesture. And another animation to zoom image back to scroll view. Like in Photos app on iPad or like videos in Safari.

Of course it would not be UIImageView. It would be some wrapper class with image inside. The main question is how to present fullscreen view. Is it must be modal view or not.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check on touching the image 
if it is small convert into full size.
if it is large convert into small size.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (isLarge) [self makeSmall];
    else [self makeFull];
}

- (void)makeFull {
    [[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];
    isLarge = YES;
    CGRect largeFrame = [self superview].bounds;
    original = self.frame;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [self setFrame:largeFrame];
    [internal setFrame:self.bounds];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
- (void)makeSmall {
    isLarge = NO;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [self setFrame:original];
    [internal setFrame:self.bounds];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: Does not worked well for me. My scroll view is not fullscreen. It located on little area on devise screen. And I need view with image to overlay all other views and become fullscreen.

Comment: Thanks Kothari bhai.. this helped me as well.. aur kaisi cahl rahi hai TCS..?

Comment: I think tera kaam bahaut aacha hai as u r searching 4 those exciting things that we have done before. I am doing only logic creation in apps via Objective C.Kaat rahe hai zindagi....."jee lenge hum, iss gum ko bhi pe lenge hum...:(".

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to this that involves both gesture recognizers and animated transitions. You remove the scrollview and add the fullscreen image. Then reverse that to return to the just the scrollview.

Use the frame of the window to determine size for the new UIImage.

The types of gesture recognizers can be adjusted to suit your needs!

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTwice = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapTwice:)];
    tapTwice.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapTwice];
}

- (void)tapOnce:(id)tapOnce {
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:0.7
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
                animations:^ {
                    [self.fullScreenImage removeFromSuperview];
                }
                completion:nil];
}

- (void)tapTwice:(id)tapTwice {
    if(self.fullScreenImage == nil){
        self.fullScreenImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.window.frame];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOnce = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapOnce:)];
        tapOnce.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [tapOnce requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapTwice];
        [self.fullScreenImage addGestureRecognizer:tapOnce];
        [self.fullScreenImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        //self.fullScreenImage = [load your image here]
    }

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view.window
                      duration:0.7
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
                    animations:^ {
                        [self.view.window addSubview:self.fullScreenImage];
                    }
                    completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Download this [sample](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser/zipball/master) for Image gallery sample code and get through it. It would definitely helps you to understand how to implement your idea.

Comment: Don't be so greedy. Samples are very educational. I always learn something from them even if it's irrelevant to my search.

Answer (score 1):

Like below you can use for zooming the image view.

```
UIView * viewForScroll;

UIImageView *imgviewForScroll;

UIScrollView *scrollToRead = [[UIScrollViewalloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(175, 5, 300, 311)];

scrollToRead.backgroundColor = [UIColordarkGrayColor];

scrollToRead.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;

scrollToRead.delegate = self;

[scrollToRead setContentSize:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400).size];

scrollToRead.maximumZoomScale = 2;

scrollToRead.minimumZoomScale = 1;

[self.view addSubview:scrollToRead];  

[scrollToRead release]; 

viewForScroll = [[UIViewalloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,400)];

[scrollToRead addSubview:viewForScroll];

[viewForScroll release];

imgviewForScroll = [[UIImageViewalloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,400)];

imgviewForScroll.image = [UIImageimageWithContentsOfFile:[arrayComicContentobjectAtIndex:0]];

[viewForScroll addSubview:imgviewForScroll];

[imgviewForScroll release];
```

//=========UIScrollView Delegate methods

```
 - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {


    return viewForScroll;
    }
```

Like to know if you need any further clarifications

Comment: hm.. this method is not appropriate for me. I need image to become fullscreen and hm... like modal. In your case it just zoomed inside scroll view. I neen scroll view stay as it is while zooming. Only image must zoom and cover scroll view behind.